# How to manually create HP recovery media?

Tags: recovery-disk

My mates HP Pavilion dv5 laptop's HDD is failing and now Windows 7 Home Premium won't boot nor will the recovery partition boot.

I took out the HDD and stuck it in a USB HDD cradle and I'm able to view the disk but I get a good few data cyclic errors so reckon HDD is toast.

Anyway, he hasn't created a recovery DVD nor USB so I'm wondering if I could manually do this? I was recently able to manually create one for a Toshiba laptop.

If it's not possible to manually create it from files on his laptop could I use a recovery DVD from another HP laptop his sister has?

HP are saying that I need to purchase a new recovery media but I'd rather avoid this if possible. I have a set of Win7 install disks so I will fresh install windows directly if the options above are non-runners!

Comment: Does his sister have a **Windows 7 Home Premium** version of Windows otherwise the product key on the bottom of the laptop won't work.

Comment: Yes, both Win7 Home Premium but different models of laptop though!

Comment: Even if you could its to late.  The source data for recovery image is toast.

Answer (score 1):

HP to HP has a reasonable chance of working.  Windows 7 has a ton of drivers built-in.  The critical parts will have drivers and work, but expect 3-4 hours of downloading and updating drivers, at least.

Comment: Thanks, I must try this tomorrow so! I didn't think these recovery media asked for the product key for Win7 so will it not think I'm installing the same version of windows on two machines? I'm aware of how long this usually takes, been unfortunate enough to have been through this a few times now :-(

Comment: @mcquaim from the **control panel** under **system** you can change the product key if it has the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always have to use HP Recovery Media you can use https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/

But you will need a product key that is on the PC unless it is a UEFI one that has a built in key to detect.

Format a flash drive 16 GB preferably as NTFS, then use command prompt type in:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

find the flash drive then type in:

```
select disk (Number)
select partition 1
active
```

then copy all files from ISO onto the flash drive directly and disable secure boot and it should boot using the old boot method.

If the other HP is the same model the recovery would work but if it isn't the Drivers and software the recovery come with will cause problems if you try to use that recovery. If I recall HP has scripts to detect if it is the original motherboard or not so if use on another HP it might say you cannot recover the PC due to incompatibility.

Modern HP's years 2018 or later should be able to use cloud recovery by HP but that requires 32 GB minimum.